# Switch to new variables

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have to move from $y(x),x  \to u(t),t$ and i have:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x^2+t^2=1\\ 
t+u+y=0\\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
Need to find $\frac{d^2 y}{{dx}^2}$.
How should i formalize it? What should i proof? Can i just diff both equations and find $\frac{dy}{dt}$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}$ from system; then coz its equal to $\frac{dy}{dx}$ i can find answer coz $\frac{d^2y}{{dx}^2}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy'}{dt}$?

UPD1(after answer): Should i proof that 1st and 2nd eq from the task is nothing but implict functions x(t) and y(t)? Because how can i diff if no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i will try to give my solution. Tell me if i'm right/wrong/unproofed.
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\dot{x}x+t=0\\ 
1+\dot{u}+\dot{y}=0\\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
Then since $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}$
We get, using prev eqs,: $y'=(1+\dot{u})\frac{x}{t}$.
Then $y''=\frac{dy'}{dx}=\frac{\dot{y'}}{\dot{x}}$;

Since $\frac{dy'}{dt}=\frac{1+\dot{u}}{t}\dot{x}+x\frac{\ddot{u}-1}{t}$ we get
$$y''=\frac{1+u^2}{t}+\frac{t^2-1}{t^3}(\ddot{u}-1)$$
Should i proof that 1st and 2nd eq from the task is nothing but implict functions x(t) and y(t)? Because how can i diff if no?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{t}{x},\frac{dy}{dt}=-1$ and hence 
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{x}{t}.$$
So
$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dy}{dx}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\frac{x}{t}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{\frac{x'(t)t-x(t)}{t^2}}{-\frac{t}{x(t)}}=-\frac{x(t)(-\frac{t^2}{x(t)}-x(t))}{t^3}=\frac{t^2+x^2(t)}{t^3}=\frac{1}{t^3}.$$

Comment: why $\frac{dy}{dt}=-1$? If i will diff the second one i will get : $1+\frac{du}{dt}+\frac{dy}{dt}=0$, no?

Comment: @EzWin, I don't know if $u$ depends on $t$ or not.

Comment: xpaul, "I have to move from $y(x),x \to u(t), t $..."